# How can a Telegram Bot find out who sent an invite link when a new member joins a channel?

Tags: http-post, bots, telegram

I'm new to bots and API requests. I'm trying to write a bot that, when it sees a new member joining by an invite link, posts a message in the channel that mentioned who invited in the new member. However, looking at the Telegram API, it seems that the User object type you can see when a new member joins doesn't track that.

Is this not possible in Telegram? If it is possible, how would I go about this? Do I have to make a bot that does it's own invite links/tracking?

Answer (score 1):

hey you can create a unique link for all of your members and when a new user joins you can check the invite link by which the user has joined. For that purpose you can use "chat_member" invite_link [here is the docs](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#chatmemberupdated) which will show the invite link used by the user.